# Не изменять ориентацию при повороте экрана

Tags: android

Здравствуйте!

Задача.
Приложение может работать или в портретном или в ландшафтном варианте(или так или так). 
При повороте экрана ориентация не должна меняться.
Ориентация должна задаваться до запуска программы или в настройках программы или любым другим способом.

Перерыл уже много всего но все не то.
Функция `setRequestedOrientation` убивает активность и в добавок будет запускаться каждый раз при запуске активности(а хотелось бы поменять ее 1 раз).
Установка параметра в манифесте `android:configChanges="orientation"` спасает от перезапуска активности, но дает кучу хлопот. Нужно самому контролировать какой `layout` загружать и опят таки `setRequestedOrientation`  будет запускаться каждый раз.

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

Проблема решилась одной строкой. `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_BEHIND);`
Теперь ориентация закрепляется в зависимости в каком положении находилось устройство (Точнее в какой положении находилась активность из которой запустили приложение).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша задача заключается, как понимаю, в том, чтобы закреплять стандартную для различного типа устройств ориентацию и запрещать ее изменять.

Один из вариантов решения проблемы приведен ниже( но нуждается в частичной доработке ):

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getWindowManager()).getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
int height = display.getHeight();
int width = display.getWidth();

int portrait = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
int landscape = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

context.setRequestedOrientation( height>=width ? portrait : landscape );
```

Использовать код следует где-нибудь на начальном этапе жизненного цикла. На всякий случай следует также исполнить в методе активности, срабатывающем при входе активности в активное состояние( `onResume()` )

Параметр активности `configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` имеет смысл лишь в том случае, если вы не планируете производить поворот экрана в соответствии с ориентацией девайса.

Comment: Как я понял идею кода, вы предлагаете решение о автоматическом определении ориентации. Автоматически определять не нужно, ориентация пусть (к примеру) устанавливается пользователем.

По поводу configChanges="screenSize|orientation", я не планирую производить поворот экрана.

Comment: Да, я понял вашу задачу. В случае, если же нужно просто зафиксировать ориентацию, которая есть на момент запуска приложения, достаточно выкинуть из кода выше 3-7 строчки.

Answer (score 1):

В своё время долго парился с проблемой. Решение работает для всех версий андроида (API) вне зависимости от того, какая ориентация (портретная или ландшафтная) является дефолтной (по умолчанию) для конкретного девайса (устройства). Решение ниже:

```
public class LockOrientation
{
Activity act;
public LockOrientation(Activity act)
{
    this.act = act;
}
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
public void lock()
{
    switch (act.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation)
    {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
            {                    act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
            else
            {
                int rotation = act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                if (rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_180)
                {
                    act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
                }
                else
                {
                    act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                }
            }
        break;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
            {
                act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
            else
            {
                int rotation = act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                if (rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_90)
                {
                    act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                }
                else
                {
                    act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
                }
            }
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Далее в нужном месте вызываем (например в onCreate()):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   new LockOrientation(this).lock();
}
```

Чтобы снять запрет на смену ориентации делаем так:

```
context.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло))

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать `setRequestedOrientation`  
А что бы активити не пересоздавалась, достаточно в манифест для нее добавить

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

И уж придется самому контролировать, какой леяут подставить в какой ориентации...  
На крайний случай, в одном xml создать в корневом элементе 2 дочерних, каждый из которых будет отвечать за отображение в каждом состоянии, и менять у них видимость

Answer (score 0):

Вот что нашёл в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#screenOrientation), и это работает:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
```

Разблокровать:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_USER);
```