# Как запретить смену ориентации экрана программно?

Tags: java, android

Проведя пальцем по экрану сверху вниз, мы попадаем вверху в меню с кнопками. Например: звук (изменить звук), поворот экрана (разрешаем или запрещаем поворот экрана) и т.д.

---

А можно ли программно нажать на кнопку "Поворот экрана", а именно: запретить поворот экрана?

Иными словами: как программно запретить поворот, а по завершении программы вернуть в положение перед запуском.
Т.е. если перед запуском был ландшафт, то он и останется им до конца работы приложения, а если был портрет, то он тоже останется до конца работы приложения?

Вариант с **android:screenOrientation="portrait"** в Манифесте
не предлагать.
Он не решает данную проблему!

Благодарю, заранее...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответы с en-SO [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28910214/3212712) и [два](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930318/3212712)

1. Получаем два варианта: ландшафт и портрет

   ```
   int orientation=this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
   if(orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
      //портрет
   }
   else{
       //ландшафт
   }
   ```
2. Получаем 4 варианта с углами поворота относительно дефолтного значения

   ```
   int rotation =  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
   int angle = 0;
   switch (rotation) {
   case Surface.ROTATION_90:
       angle = -90;
       break;
   case Surface.ROTATION_180:
       angle = 180;
       break;
   case Surface.ROTATION_270:
       angle = 90;
       break;
   default:
       angle = 0;
       break;
   }
   ```

Теперь устанавливайте полученную ориентацию:

```
setRequestedOrientation(/* сюда поместите одно из значений констант класса ActivityInfo */);
```

Comment: Все вроде нормально, но не определяет при запуске переворот на 180 градусов:
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
                break;

Comment: @ЛЕО, на всех устройствах не определяет?

Comment: Практически на всех. Стандартный лаунчер не может переворачивать экран на 180 градусов.

Comment: @ЛЕО, ну, видимо придётся в этом случае использовать 0 градусов и ругаться на прогеров из гугла)

Comment: Объясню, почему я так добиваюсь 180 градусов. Дело в том, что я левша (у меня нет кисти правой руки), я все делаю левой рукой, в том числе и управляю автомобилем тоже. И таких как я, не мало.
Т.к. производители гаджетов в основном располагают кнопки для правой руки, мне это крайне не удобно и по возможности, я использую леворукие программы, когда можно перевернуть экран на 180 градусов.

Comment: @ЛЕО, насколько я нагуглил ориентации экранов - большая проблема и стандарта тут нет. Каждый производитель по своему делает и универсального кода нет( Но, может, вот отсюда ещё код поможет: [тык](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10383164/3212712)

Comment: ЮрийСПб! Наконец-то я нашел устройство, в котором можно запустить приложение вверх ногами: т.е. с поворотом на 180 градусов. Ваш код работает. Вопрос снят, благодарю!

Comment: @ЛЕО, рад был помочь)

Answer (score 1):

Вот что нашёл в документации, и это работает:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
```

Разблокировать:

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_USER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Все с того же en-SO:

```
public class LockOrientation {
Activity activity;

public LockOrientation(Activity act) {
    this.activity = act;
}

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
public void lock() {
    switch (activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation) {
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else {
            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getRotation();
            if (rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_90
                    || rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_180) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
            } else {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
        }
        break;
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getRotation();
            if (rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_0
                    || rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_90) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            } else {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

public void unlock() {
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}
```

}

Вызов:
блокировка: `new LockOrientation(this).lock();`
разблокировка: `new LockOrientation(this).unlock();`

Comment: Этот же код на ru-SO: [тык](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/353555/17609)

Comment: В следующий раз обещаю обновить страницу, перед тем как написать

Comment: Не очень понял при чём тут обновление страницы)

Comment: не правильно прочел Ваше сообщение