# Как изменить положение экрана при горизонтальной ориентации?

Tags: android

Написал простенькую игру, где нужно управлять ракетой и уворачиваться от летящих на тебя астероидов. Ориентация горизонтальная, однако пользователь держит устройство вертикально. И тут та и есть проблема. Игроку необходимо держать устройство не со снизу, как обычно, где находятся кнопки домой, назад и т.п, а сверху, где есть камера. Есть какой-нибудь способ исправить это недоразумение?Там прописать какое-нибудь параметр в манифесте или что-еще... Очень нужна помощь)

Comment: Возможно это то, что нужно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507556/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be

Comment: Он не это имеет ввиду, ему в манифесте надо прописать реверсный режим ориентации

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавь к активности в манифесте

```
android:screenOrientation="reversePortrait"
```

Тут можно посмотреть все режимы:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html?hl=ru#screen

Comment: Спасибо, использовал setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);